# aggregating from multiple tables on posgres not working

Tags: mysql, postgresql, subquery, aggregate-functions

I need to  count data from 2 tables and shown them in single output

I have 2 tables

```
branches 
atms
```

i need to show output like below

```
bank_id atms branches
1        20  30
```

**The query below works perfectly on mysql but no luck in posgres**

```
SELECT * from (
    (SELECT count(*)  FROM branches where bank_id=30) as branch_count  ,

    (SELECT count(*)   FROM atms where  bank_id=30) as atm_count
    )tmp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just looking at one bank_id you dont need that many subqueries:

```
SELECT  (SELECT count(*)  FROM branches where bank_id=30) as branch_count  ,
        (SELECT count(*)   FROM atms where  bank_id=30) as atm_count
```

However, if you want to get all stats, for all banks, assuming you have a table `banks` to hold all the `bank_ids`, then following query would help:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    banks B
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT BR.bank_id, count(*) branch_count FROM branches BR GROUP BY BR.bank_id) as BC
             ON BC.bank_id = B.bank_id
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT AT.bank_id, count(*) atm_count  FROM atms AT GROUP BY AT.bank_id) as AC
             ON AC.bank_id = B.bank_id
```